# Create custom aggregate functions that I can apply to any field in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to be able to calculate the 25th percentile of any field in Power BI. For example, I want it to function like how the Sum, Average, Minimum, etc. options work.

[image]

So far, all I've been able to do is create a new measure, but this requires me to select a specific field to do the calculation on.

For example, I can create a measure like this:

```
Measure 2 = PERCENTILE.INC('S&P 500'[Assets], .25)
```

But that calculation can only apply to Assets, and I would have to manually create a new measure for every field that I want to calculate the 25th percentile for.

Comment: You ask for your own function creation (makes sense) I am afraid you need to talk to Microsoft, as far as I know this functionality is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Aldert, there is no standard function, you could try suggesting an idea through the [Power BI Ideas forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas).

A workaround could be through adding a custom table through Add Data with one column and the name of a measure on each row. You could than make a master measure which uses a SWITCH() to determine which measure to calculate and return the percentile. Creating a slicer or filter to select the measure name would finish it off. It could be a solution when you have a lot of measures and don't want to double the amount of measures in your report but I think creating individual measures is easier and less work. This is because DAX has no equivalent of INDIRECT() in Excel, meaning you still have to code every new measure manually into the SWITCH().

```
Measure = 
    var _calculation = 
        SWITCH ( SELECTEDVALUE( Slicer[Measure Name] ; "Please select a measure" ) ;
            "Assets" ; [Assets] ;
            "Liabilities" ; [Liabilities] ;
            // etc.
            0
        )
RETURN
    PERCENTILE.INC ( _calculation ; ,25 )
```